# Integrate Cognito with exisiting users table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, kohana

I'm still a learner, please forgive me if I ask a simple question. I have an application which contains its own users table where I store the email and password. When the user logs in I store the user's information (without the password) in session and privilege IDs (so that I can manage who gets to see each page after the login).

I integrated a Cognito login. How should the integration with the existing users table work? After a successful Cognito login I get a token back. Can someone write me how do I integrate the Cognito token with existing users table? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito returns a JWT token which can be decoded via libraries like https://jwt.io/

The output will be somewhat like

[image: Decoded Cognito Token]

For your use case use "cognito:username" to identify the user and store an event against it

Comment: That's what I thought. I decoded the token with `spomky-labs/jose` library and got the email back. Thank you Asfar.